# RVL-CDIP dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

How can I import or Download RVL-CDIP dataset fastly?

I have already done a lot of research to get any type of link so that I can directly import it in my Jupyter notebook but I cannot get anything.

Answer (score 3):

This will download the dataset and save the file under name 'rvl-cdip' in your notebook folder

`!wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc" -O rvl-cdip && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("aharley/rvl_cdip")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the RVL-CDIP dataset from the Hugging Face Datasets Hub using TensorFlow, since the RVL-CDIP dataset is available on TensorFlow Datasets (TFDS).

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# Load the RVL-CDIP dataset
ds = tfds.load('huggingface:rvl_cdip', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
```

Once loaded, the `ds` object will be used for further processing and training machine learning models.