# Unpacking a tar.gz file results in error: error is not recoverable

Tags: gzip, tar, gunzip

The file is very large (38Gb, RVL-CDIP dataset, https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc&export=download), I downloaded it using this trick: [RVL-CDIP dataset on google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645004/rvl-cdip-dataset-on-google-colab)

When I use `tar -xvf rvl_cdip.tar.gz` I get the error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format 
tar: Child returned status 1 
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I  also tried gunzip, and it returned the same error. I'm honestly at loss what to do.

Comment: Add output of `file rvl_cdip.tar.gz` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm sorry I don't quite get what you mean. Feel free to amend the question

Comment: Please provide the first 20 bytes of the file in hexadecimal in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is download it again, perhaps not using whatever "trick" it is you are referring to.

I simply clicked on the link to download the file, and there's nothing wrong with it. It verifies correctly with gzip -t, and tar lists the directories and files within, 817,491 of them.

It is 38,762,320,458 bytes in length with SHA-256 `3577e655813922098cd776422479017be37612ec17a65076b1b62199bf8b28a2`. The uncompressed tar file is 49,061,058,560 bytes with CRC `f3b0e8c1`.

Comment: This solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204877/rvl-cdip-dataset. It downloaded a file without tar.gz extension, and I thought it was corrupt, but for some reason tar -xvf rvl-cdip worked. I unpacked the file (took about 30min), no errors reported

Comment: The problem is, without the trick, I don't understand how to download a file like this. Wget doesn't find it out of the box

Comment: All I did was click the link in your question in my browser, and it downloaded the file. No trick needed.

Comment: Yes I know. The tricky bit is to download it with wget and open

Answer (score 0):

Your file is either corrupted or not actually gzip compressed. You can try downloading it again and possibly verifying checksums or renaming to rvl_cdip.tar if some download program gunzipped it for you transparently.  You can check with `file rvl_cdip.tar.gz`

Comment: file returned 'data', renaming into .tar didn't help (not a tar file)

Comment: @Alex: Your file is broken. Correct output: `gzip compressed data`

Comment: In such case do you know how to wget download a file from here:https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc&export=download